# How to write zsh alias for pushing new branch from current local branch?

Tags: git, bash, unix, zsh, zshrc

Right now when i commit and want to push and create remote branch I did:

```
app_folder (some_branch)> git push -u origin some_branch:some_branch
```

Is there a way to write zsh alias ex: `gpu` which get name of current branch and do that without my help?

Comment: Yes. However, what it looks like depends on how bullet-proof you want it to be. The basic idea would be to parse the output of `git branch` to get your current branch, although that will be problematic of you're not on a branch (i.e. detached HEAD state).

Comment: Maybe something like this: ``echo `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` ``

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's a very basic script. Some additional features (and error checking!) are probably needed, but it works:

```
#!/bin/zsh
function branch() {
    ref=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD)
    echo "${ref#refs/heads/}"
}
# TODO: Let the user set the remote to push to? 
git push -u origin ${branch}:${branch}
```

The `branch()` function is taken from Oh-My-ZSH [`git_prompt_info()`](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/lib/git.zsh) - it's used to put the current `git branch` into the `PROMPT`.

This would probably work rather well as a `zsh` function, rather than an alias.

Comment: Shouldn't the last line end with `$(branch):$(branch)`?

Comment: @user4815162342 Possibly... both `${branch}` and `$(branch)` seem to work. I can't remember where in the `man` pages the difference between the two syntaxes is outlined, though, so I'm not sure which is better / preferred.

Comment: Interesting, I would have expected `${branch}` to be replaced with the value of `branch` variable, just like `$branch`, and `$(branch)` to be replaced with the output of the `branch` command or shell function, just like `\`branch\``. This is documented under PARAMETER EXPANSION and COMMAND SUBSTITUTION in [`zshexpn(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zshexpn).

Comment: As a note for future users stumbling upon this. ${branch} does not work on version "4.3.11 (i386-apple-darwin12.0)" of zsh. $(branch) must be used.